# Shell Directory Backup and Restore

Tags: shell, backup, tar, restore

I have been making script that will back up and restore a directory. I want to make it better but I need some help.

At the moment the I have the file being saved as just `backup.tgz` I did have the `date` added onto the end but when I ran the restore function the I could only have it look for the `backup.tgz` and not the backup with the date extension. Is there any way to have it look for the most recent backup? Or even look for the backup given by user input?

I have also tried to add a progress bar and make incremental back ups but had no luck there either if someone could help?

**Tar Code**

```
#!/bin/bash

ROOT="/Users/Rory/Documents"
ROOT_EXCLUDE="--exclude=/dev --exclude=/proc --exclude=/sys --exclude=/temp --exclude=/run --exlucde=/mnt --exlcude=/media --exlude=$
DESTIN="/Users/Rory/BackUps"
BACKUP="backup.tgz"
CREATE="/dev /proc /sys /temp /run /mnt /media "

if [ "$USER" != "root" ]; then
    echo "You are not the root user"
    echo "To use backup please use: sudo backup"
    exit
fi

clear

echo "************************************************"
echo "********* Backup Menu **************************"
echo "************************************************"

OPTIONS="BACKUP RESTORE DESTINATION EXIT"
LIST="1)BACKUP 2)RESTORE 3)DESTINATION 4)EXIT"

select opt in $OPTIONS; do
if [ "$opt" = "EXIT" ]; then
    echo "GOODBYE!"
    sleep 3
    clear
    exit

elif [ "$opt" = "BACKUP" ]; then
    echo "BACKING UP FILES..."
    sleep 2
    tar cvpfz $DESTIN/backup.tgz $ROOT $ROOT_EXCLUDE
    echo "BACKUP COMPLETE"
    sleep 2
    clear
    echo $LIST

elif [ "$opt" = "RESTORE" ]; then
    echo "RESTOTING FILES..."
    sleep 2
    tar xvpfz $DESTIN/$BACKUP -C /Users/Rory/BackUps
    sleep 2
    if [[ -e "/proc" ]]; then
            echo "$CREATE already exists! "
    else
            mkdir $CREATE
            echo "$CREATE are created! "
    fi
    echo "RESTORE COMPLETE..."
    clear
    exit

elif [ "$opt" = "DESTINATION" ]; then
    echo "CURRENT DESTINATION: $DESTIN/backup.tgz "
    echo "TO CHANGE ENTER THE NEW DESTINATION..."
    echo "TO LEAVE IT AS IS JUST PRESS ENTER..."
    read NEW_DESTIN

    #IF GREATER THEN 0 ASSIGN NEW DESTINATION
    if [ ${#NEW_DESTIN} -gt 0 ]; then
            DESTIN = "$NEW_DESTIN"
    fi
    clear

else
    clear
    echo "BAD INPUT!"
    echo "ENTER 1 , 2, 3 or 4.."
    echo $LIST


fi
done
```

Comment: What question are you asking here specifically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in the code snippet you posted, you are only looking for backup.tgz.

If you wanted to pick a specific one, you could modify your script to accept an argument and pick one based on a string you input. Or...if you wanted to do based on "how old", you could sort the backup files by date and allow the user to pick 0th, 1st, 2nd, etc.

One thing you  may want to check out is rsync. Rsync can only copy files that have changed.

Plus, you can also enable a progress bar with rsync = )

`rsync -avP /source/path/ /dest/path/`

Check out the man page for more details `man rsync`

To enable progress bar on restore, you can untar the file and use rsync in reverse, and then you have progress updates = )

If you want to make this a custom numeric progress bar you'll probably need to do something more complicated than simply taking output from rsync.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, If i wanted to use rsync in the above code would I just have to change the tar lines with the appropriate rsync ones? or is there more to rsync?

Comment: I'd rsync first then tar the destination folder.

Comment: How would I go about that? I have been looking around but cant find any tutorials on combining the two

Comment: I'd suggest you go slowly. Completely understand rsync first, what its capabilities are, how to use it, then use tar after that.